# Error:(32, 13) Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:10.0.1

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, google-cloud-firestore, android-library

I Want to add Firestore in app, my android studio version is 2.3.2, but i am unable to see firestore option in Firebase assistant, And when i am adding librar for Firestore:-

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:10.0.1'
```

it is showing me this error:-

```
Error:(32, 13) Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:10.0.1
```

Please help me out with this problem !!

this is my app level build gradel file:-

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "in.anew.trysafeblog"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.5.+'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:10.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Please help me out !!!
build gradle file:-

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2'

        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
        //classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: You may add the detailed log of "Failed to resolve".

Answer (score 1):

To solve this, please change the following lines of code:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
```

to

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
```

And please also don't forget to add:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
```

To your build.gradle file. Please see [here](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android) more info.

Comment: still showing this error                                                                                         
 Error:(34, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'implementation()'
Possible causes:The project 'TrySafeBlog' may be using a version of the Android Gradle plug-in that does not contain the method (e.g. 'testCompile' was added in 1.1.0).
The project 'TrySafeBlog' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.

Comment: In this case try to update Android Gradle to `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'`. Does it work now?

Answer (score 0):

Use

on your **app/build.gradle**

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.2'
```

on your **project/build.gradle**

```
buildscript {

    repositories { 

        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
        }
    } 

    dependencies { 
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2' 
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong 
        // in the individual module build.gradle files 
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1' 
    } 
} 
allprojects { 
    repositories { 

        jcenter() 
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    } 
} 
task clean(type: Delete) { delete rootProject.buildDir }
```

Comment: This artifact is deprecated

Comment: Still not Working

Comment: Error:(34, 13) Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:15.0.0

Comment: Error:(33, 13) Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:15.0.0

Comment: Error:(35, 13) Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:15.0.0

Comment: Put your `project/build.gradle`, pls! I want see if you is point to correct repository

Comment: i have pasted my    project/build.gradle    file.

Comment: Error:(5, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'google()'    
    Possible causes: The project 'TrySafeBlog' may be using a version of the Android Gradle plug-in that does not contain the method Upgrade plugin to version 2.3.2 and sync project    The project 'TrySafeBlog' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.